# Examples of $\Sigma_2^p$ complete problems?

Tags: complexity-classes, polynomial-hierarchy

I need a list of $\Sigma_2^p$ complete languages. There are two such problems listed in the [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aS), namely:

- Minimum equivalent DNF. Given a DNF formula F and integer k, is there a DNF formula equivalent to F with k or fewer occurences of literals?
- Shortest implicant. Given a formula F and integer k, is there a conjunction of k or fewer literals that implies F?

Another basic $\Sigma_2^p$ complete problem:

- $\Sigma_i \text{SAT}$. Given a quantified boolean formula $\varphi$ of the form $\varphi = \exists \vec{u} \forall \vec{v}\, \phi(\vec{u}, \vec{v})$, is $\varphi$ valid?

However, I am hopefully looking for a problem which makes use of graphs (e.g. a clique related problem).

Comment: Take a look at this compendium: http://ovid.cs.depaul.edu/documents/phcom.pdf

Comment: This looks extremely useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HuckBennett: good survey! Why don't you turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Marcus Schaefer and Chris Umans have [a nice Garey-and-Johnson-esque survey](http://ovid.cs.depaul.edu/documents/phcom.pdf) of complete problems in the polynomial hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

A rather recent result not included in the Schaefer and Umans paper is **2-CLIQUE COLOURING OF PERFECT GRAPHS**.

See  David Defossez, [Complexity of clique-coloring odd-hole-free graphs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1598868). J. Graph Theory 62, 2 (October 2009), 139-156, and some recent improvements (2013): Hélio B. Macêdo Filho, Raphael C. S. Machado, Celina M. H. de Figueiredo, [Hierarchical complexity of 2-clique-colouring weakly chordal graphs and perfect graphs having cliques of size at least 3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2086) (the problem is still $\Sigma_2^p$-complete for weakly chordal graphs, and for perfect graphs having cliques of size at least 3).

Answer (score 7):

Deciding the existence of an "evolutionarily stable strategy" in a normal-form game. See http://www.cs.duke.edu/~conitzer/ess.pdf .

The setup is a 2-player symmetric game. An evolutionarily stable strategy is a (randomized) strategy that is (a) a symmetric nash equilibrium, and (b) there are no good "symmetric deviations": in this equilibrium, if one player can deviate to some strategy and maintain equal utility, then the other player would do strictly worse to then also deviate to this strategy.